How to solve " could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer" error?
I'm trying to build a netbox on ECS (fargate), with RDS (postgreSQL) as database and elasticache (redis) as cache server. My goal is to have the configuration as shown in the link below, but it does not start.
https://engineers.ntt.com/entry/202408-netbox-porting/entry
※I'm trying to implement this from the AWS management console instead of using CDK.
I have set up and deployed the necessary information, but I get the following error in the RDS log
:LOG: could not accept SSL connection: EOF detected

The netbox table was created when the ECS service was started, so I think connection is fine...
I would like to know how can I solve this issue
※sorry for my poor English
Here is my information
PostgreSQL:16.3
Here is What I tried
1.Review security groups configuration
2.Review ECS task definitions (endpoint names, password , and ports to make sure they are correct)
3.Change rds.force.ssl in RDS parameter group from 1 to 0
4.Change DB_SSLMODE=disable in ECS environment variable
